# React Ref Form onSubmit Handler not triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form.

I try to submit this form from a different function.

To do so I created a `ref`. This ref, when printed, has the correct HTML Node and this node also has an `submit` method. When this submit method is called (`formNode.submit()`) the form get's submitted, **but** the `onSubmit` handler is never triggered.

Why?

Here is a simplified example which shows the same behavior.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.form = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.form.submit()}>
        Click me!
        <form
          onSubmit={e => console.log(e)}
          ref={f => (this.form = f)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vm8pkmony

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For your specific use case, you'll have to fire the `submit` event of the form using `dispatchEvent`.

```
this.form.dispatchEvent(new Event("submit"));
```

Answer (score 32):

Starting from React 17 you have to add `cancelable` and `bubbles` properties to your event. Otherwise, the solution from the accepted answer won't work. It's caused by some [changes in event delegation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#changes-to-event-delegation).

```js
this.form.dispatchEvent(
    new Event("submit", { cancelable: true, bubbles: true })
);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

When you call the form's `submit` function, the `submit` event is not fired.

This behaviour is intended because we're assuming that if you called `submit` directly you already validated your form.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question but we can do something like this;

As [Ramon Balthazar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2433519/ramon-balthazar) mentioned above;

> When you call the form's submit function, the submit event is not
> fired.

To solve this problem, we can create hidden button and add reference to it, than we can click that button with ref, it will submit the form and trigger submit event;

```
import { useRef } from 'react'

export default function Form(props) {
    const hiddenButtonRef = useRef(null)

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => console.log(e)}>
                <input type="submit" style={{ display: 'none' }} ref={hiddenButtonRef} />
            </form>

            <div onClick={() => hiddenButtonRef.current.click()}>Click me!</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: OP said "I try to submit this form from a different function." - so the question is how to programatically submit the form AND trigger the onSubmit.

Comment: This approach worked for me! Note that, for TypeScript, I needed: `const hiddenButtonRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)`

Answer (score 3):

UPDATED solution currently I use `formRef.current.requestSubmit()`

```js
  const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);


  const onClickCheckout = () => {
    if (formRef.current) {
      formRef.current.scrollIntoView({ block: "nearest", behavior: "smooth" });
      formRef.current.requestSubmit();
    }
  };
`
```

Answer (score 1):

For people in 2021 using functional component:

You have to include a `<button>` **inside of** the form, and there is no need to add other props to trigger the `onSubmit` event of `<form>`!

For example:

```
    <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
            <h1 style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>Import Your Space</h1>
            <InputText label="space-id" ref={spaceIdRef}
                       init={spaceId} onChange={value => setSpaceId(value)}/>
            <InputText label="map-id" ref={mapIdRef}
                       init={mapId} onChange={value => setMapId(value)}/>
            <InputTextArea label="rooms" ref={roomsRef}
                           init={rooms} onChange={value => setRooms(value)}/>
            <button style={{background: "lightgreen", alignSelf: "flex-end"}}>
                Start Discrimination</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```