# React - Trigger form submit using useRef

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, onsubmit, use-ref

Good day, so I am trying to perform an intermediate function before a form action="POST" takes place. Ive tried two things firstly onSubmit={functionName} but the form always performs the action even if in the onSubmit function I return false. Secondly ive been trying to useRef instead to dispatch the submit event programtically but nothing happens? I essentially have to do a server side call to get a config for the form values that gets posted, unfortunately the external API I use needs the form to be submitted in this way. Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Attempt 1:

```
const performSubmit =() => {
 //Using onSubmit and then only performing the return after the axios call is done
 axiosCallFunction.then((res) => {
   setConfig(res.data)
   return true
 }).catch((error)) => {
   //Dont submit form
   return false
 })
}

return (
<form name="form" onSubmit={performSubmit} id="x1" method="POST" action="https://url.aspx" target="_top">
    <input value={config.param}/>
    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>)
```

Attempt 2

```
const formEl = useRef();

const performSubmit =() => {
 //Currently not calling the submit on the form
 formEl.current.dispatchEvent(new Event("submit"))
}

return (
<form name="form" ref={formEl} id="x1" method="POST" action="https://url.aspx" target="_top">
    <input value={config.param}/>
    <button onClick={performSubmit} />
</form>)
```

Essentially want to do some call to a server and get results back before I submit the form or perform the action for the form.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
formEl.current && formEl.current.submit();
```

?

Answer (score 5):

> Starting from React 17 you have to add `cancelable` and `bubbles` properties to your event. Otherwise, the solution from the accepted answer won't work. It's caused by some [changes in event delegation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#changes-to-event-delegation).

> ```js
> formEl?.current.dispatchEvent(
>   new Event("submit", { cancelable: true, bubbles: true })
> );
> ```

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66659749/85882).

Answer (score 3):

works with me

```
  const fromRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>()
```

form:

```
<form ref={fromRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

btn:

```
  <Button onClick={() => {
      fromRef.current.requestSubmit()

    }} colorScheme='blue'>Save</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the event then prevent its default action

```
const performSubmit =(e) => {

 // stop the form from actually submitting
 e.preventDefault();

 //Using onSubmit and then only performing the return after the axios call is done
 axiosCallFunction.then((res) => {
   setConfig(res.data)
   return true
 }).catch((error)) => {
   //Dont submit form
   return false
 })
}
```

pass the event

```
return (
<form name="form" onSubmit={(e) => performSubmit(e)} id="x1" method="POST" action="https://url.aspx" target="_top">
    <input value={config.param}/>
    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, for some reason e.preventDefault() no longer triggers the action on the form even after the return true.

Comment: yes, I thought you wanted to handle everything manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
form?.current.dispatchEvent(new Event("submit"));
```